# How to include interactive java-based web pages inside LaTeX generated PDF documents

Tags: pdftex, online

Is it possible to open an interactive web page, [such as this](http://web.monroecc.edu/manila/webfiles/calcNSF/JavaCode/CalcPlot3D.htm), inside a latex generated pdf page?

Comment: Hopefully related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6692621

Comment: Java embedded in PDFs is a notorious source of security exploits. Only your most naïve users will ever click on your buttons.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not unless you program a PDF viewer that includes a JRE. AFAIK Adobe Reader does not.