# Can include text which conditionally appears depending on PDF viewer?

Tags: pdftex, pdf, conditionals, viewers

Can you have a message in a document which only appears when particular PDF viewers are used?

I am using pdflatex to create a PDF document. I am including pdf image which, unfortunately, does not render correctly either in OSX Preview or Gnome Linux evince, but does render correctly on other viewers I have tried. When one of the offending viewers is used, I would like a warning message to appear in the caption of the figure.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) for first Q. It's `pdf viewer` specfic issue so `pdflatex` might not be aware. I suggest you can typeset "Best Viewed in Evince(for example) and Typesetting using pdflatex" Related: [Can we have viewer specific text in a pdf generated by pdfLaTex?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/102022/15717)